# Arduino IDE Unable to detect ZumoMotor.H ( PIXY PET )

Tags: c++, arduino, robotics, arduino-ide

I trying to make the pixy pet work for my project.
https://learn.adafruit.com/pixy-pet-robot-color-vision-follower-using-pixycam/playing-with-your-pet.

I used the given code for the arduino IDE, but i keep on getting this error
Arduino: 1.5.7 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

```
sketch_sep17a.ino:27:24: fatal error: ZumoMotors.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.

---

The Code, im using, was given by the official maker of the Pixy Pet.
Please have a look. ( https://learn.adafruit.com/pixy-pet-robot-color-vision-follower-using-pixycam/the-code)

Answer (score 1):

Better post this question in Arduino Stack Exchange http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Meanwhile, did you download ZumoMotos.h library?

If not, download it and copy to the same file of your .ino

https://github.com/pololu/zumo-shield/blob/master/ZumoMotors/ZumoMotors.h

Comment: Sorry, you mind giving me the exact location where to put the files at? im kinda new to arduino. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Not sure about it right now.

Try to save your current .ino, then search that folder and copy it there.